# POJO for rest Get call to return a nested complex json in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi i need work flow(how to create pojo structure and how to communicate ) to create below json structure for a REST API get Call.

please help me out

```
[
  {
   "id":"1", 
   "Nmae":"gourav",
    "Gender":"Male",
     "usertype":{
                 "Typeone":"Admin",
                 "Status":"Active"
                 }
                {
                  "Typetwo":"Agent",
                  "Status":"Disabled"
                  }
  },
  {
   "id":"2", 
   "Nmae":"satya",
    "Gender":"Male",
     "usertype":{
                 "Typeone":"Admin",
                 "Status":"disabled"
                 }
                {
                  "Typetwo":"Agent",
                  "Status":"active"
                  }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow something like this,

---

The controller class, where you will define your routes -

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces({ javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getUser(){

    // Create Object of your DAO or Service class and use getUserDetails() to return a list of users, maybe from the Database.
    List<User> usersList = serviceExampleObject.getUserDetails();

    //Set the list field to the response object
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(usersList).build();
}
```

If you want to follow SpringBoot Approach, your controller will be -

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUsers(){

        List<Users> usersList = userService.getUsersDetail();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(usersList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Create a User PoJo (Didn't add all getter/setters to make the post short)-

```
class User{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private List<UserType> userType;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ...
    ...

    public void setUserType(List<UserType> userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
}
```

Create a UserType PoJo -

```
class UserType{
    private String typeNumber;
    private String typeRole;
    private String status;

    public String getTypeNumber() {
        return typeNumber;
    }
    ...
    ...

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Also, the json response needs to be modified a bit. In the userType field, you can have fields with different names, so, i would suggest to follow the below approach :

```
"usertype": [
    {
        "typeNumber": "one",
        "typeRole": "Admin",
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "typeNumber": "two",
        "typeRole": "Agent",
        "status": "Disabled"
    }
]
```

Comment: @GURU I have added the code snippet for RestController, see if this helps. Thank You

Comment: thanks i will look on it.I think it will work. if any i will comment.Any how thanks for quick reply

Comment: thanks @Dusayanta Prasad.. its working.....

Comment: @GURU You are welcomed, don't forget to upvote the answer if you are able to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class named User with the fields you want and use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` so something like:

```
@Produces({ javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
Response getUser(){
    User user = new User();
    //set fields
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(user).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create two classes one for `user` and another for `UserType`

```
Public Class UserType {

  private String type;
  private String status;

//Constructor, Getters and Setters, etc.
}




Public Class User {

  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String gender;
  private UserType userType;

//Constructor, Getters and Setters, etc.
}
```

Then when you return the `User` it will also return the `UserType`corresponding in a json like the one you described above. it should look like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(PARAMS_IF_ANY) {

  // Application logic to find the user
  return user;

}
```

and the trick is done

Comment: thanks for your reply....as u said i have already two classes but i want how to communicate